# Where can I find some solid/up-to-date LoL champion guides?

Tags: league-of-legends

See topic...

Also I remember watching some great live feeds of good players, but I can't seem to find them again, so I'd love some direction there as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Leaguecraft (http://leaguecraft.com/) has many user submitted guides -- if you can't find anything on the official LoL forums (the Guides/Strategies forum) that's where I'd check (you didn't mention a particular champion, or I would have gotten more specific)

[Solomid.net](http://Solomid.net) has a lot of good streams of top players. You can see either live or previously streamed matches.

Comment: Sweet, I'll give them a good look!

Answer (score 4):

[www.mobafire.com](http://www.mobafire.com) has some good guides as well.

Comment: The mobafire community gives out a lot more guides than the other sites.

Answer (score 2):

The Counter Logic Gaming livestream is a good one: http://clgaming.net/livestream.php.  They're the team that won the WCG.

Answer (score 1):

[**This**](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=68225) thread on the LoL forums is a pretty good list.

A lot of those are on mobafire or leaguecraft, but the forums can be good for seeing what specific problems other people have with certain builds.